# CentOS server blocking own outgoing traffic

Tags: centos, iptables, fail2ban

I've got a server (CentOS 6.7) running, which causes me some headaches.

A few months ago, the website running on the server was unavailable. After some digging, it appeared that Iptables was blocking the server's own outgoing traffic. This happened by a rule automatically added by (I think) fail2ban.

Today, I got a similar problem; now the server was blocking outgoing traffic to two specific IP's, which are, unfortunately, important for the applications running on the server.

I've removed the rules, so now it's all working again, but how do I prevent this from happening again? How do I prevent fail2ban (and maybe friends) from adding rules which block outgoing traffic?

Answer (score 2):

You can do [whitelisting in fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist) by adding specific ip or network in the `ignoreip` list in `jail.local` file. You will need to add it in `[DEFAULT]` block.

```
[DEFAULT]
# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not                          
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be                             
# defined using space separator.                                     

ignoreip = 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.0/24 8.8.8.8
```